# Error 1064 during trigger creation

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to create a trigger on one of the tables, it's very simple, just to set one value - but I always get error 1064

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_TEST` BEFORE INSERT ON `TEST_table` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
        IF NEW.as_src = 13335 THEN
            SET NEW.peer_as_src = 13335;
        END IF
END
```

And get this error:

> Error SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the default delimiter

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_TEST` BEFORE INSERT ON `TEST_table` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
        IF NEW.as_src = 13335 THEN
            SET NEW.peer_as_src = 13335;
        END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Otherwise the statement will end at the first `;` which would make the trigger definition incomplete.

Comment: The [BEGIN..END](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/begin-end.html) and [Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) in the MySQL docs for reference.

Comment: Thanks - tried to change delimiter but probably I had some error in syntax - now everything is working fine :)

Comment: Thank you, re-setting the default delimiter to ";" after the trigger creation was the missing thing for my part